# Container to match image height from url

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have a flexible container with dynamic height. I tried to remove the height from the container but the image dissapears.

This is what I have now with fixed height

```
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 400,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                image: NetworkImage(article.imageSrc),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```flutter
Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,       
            child: Image.network(article.imageSrc),
          ),
```

Comment: I guess the container by default will use the child height but due to `decoration` that didnt work. Thanks!